# Why this tree is not a balanced tree

Tags: tree

The answer said this tree is not a balanced tree. But I think it is.

The only definition that I know is:
The left and right subtrees' heights differ by at most one, AND
The left subtree is balanced, AND
The right subtree is balanced

Is there any other definition of the balanced tree?

[image]

Comment: There are different definitions of "balanced tree", which one are you referring to?

Comment: The only definition that I know is: 1. The left and right subtrees' heights differ by at most one, AND
The left subtree is balanced, AND
The right subtree is balanced. Is there any other definition?

Comment: Yes, there is balance based on weight, or balance that allows more than 1 difference, or balance where all the leaves should not be spread over more than 2 levels.... Can you quote the larger context?